# Generating the .war file from maven dependency project

Tags: maven

Here I have two projects those are **project(1)** and **project(2)**.

I am going to generate a *.war* file for the **project(1)** but it depends on **project(2)**.

I built the **project(2)** as a *.jar* file and added it to the **project(1)**'s build path but while runnig `mvn install` it results in compilation errors like:

```
package com.disha.db.dao.orm.gen does not exist` the package is in the project(2).
```

Can any one please help to me.

Comment: How are you generating the project(2) Can you share the pom.xml for both projects

Answer (score 0):

You have to delegate dependency management to **Maven** and that's actually where it comes in hand, otherwise you can move on packaging and resolving inter-projects dependencies by hand and let the *Maven alternative* be dropped.

You should make sure you have provided the correct *Project Object Module* description for your projects (pom.xm) along with tha packaging type.

Then since you want the **project(2)** to be availble for **project(1)** at compilation time, you have to declare, *project(2)* as a **dependency of** *project(1)*.

- *project(2) pom.xml* (I will refer to it as *project-2* since 'project(2)' does not match a valid id pattern.):

```
  <project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>project2.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

  </project>
```

Now the *project(1)* will refer to the `project-2` artifact as a dependency with scope `compile`:

```
  <project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>project1.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>project2.group.id</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-2</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>

  </project>
```

*Note: Update the group and artifact IDs with ones you are using*.

Comment: I'm delighted to be with much help. Feel free to accept the answer and upvote it to make it eligible for future visitors :)